# In Python's rdflib, get Subgraph of only Connected Nodes

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I'm using `rdflib` to turn data (entered by a user through a GUI) into RDF data.

The structure of this data is relatively complex, with objects referencing each other, and all that stuff.
The way I'm doing it is basically, to loop over all objects, creating its graph, and then adding all these graphs together.

This works nicely so far. But now I'm running into cases, where an object does not reference any other object and is referenced by none.
This leads to a graph then, that is entirely detached from the rest of the graph.

I could in theory check for every object, if it has connections to another object, before adding it to the graph, but that would be annoyingly complex. Is it by any chance possible through `rdflib`, to get the subgraph of a graph, that is "everything that's connected to a certain node"?

### Update

For clarification, here's an example what I mean:

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/stuff/1.0/> . 

ex:main-thing a ex:thing ;
    ex:hasTitle "The main Thing" ;
    ex:isRelatedTo ex:thing-01 ;
    ex:isRelatedTo ex:thing-02 .

ex:thing-01 a ex:thing;
    ex:hasTitle "Thing 1" ;
    ex:hasDescription "Is referenced by the main thing." .

ex:thing-02 a ex:thing;
    ex:hasTitle "Thing 2" ;
    ex:hasDescription "Is referenced by the main thing, like thing 1." .

ex:thing-03 a ex:thing;
    ex:hasTitle "Thing 3" ;
    ex:isRelatedTo ex:main-thing ;
    ex:hasDescription "Is referencing the main thing itself." .

ex:thing-04 a ex:thing;
    ex:hasTitle "Thing 4" ;
    ex:isRelatedTo ex:thing-01 ;
    ex:hasDescription "Is connected to main thing via thing 1." .

ex:thing-05 a ex:thing;
    ex:hasTitle "Thing 5" ;
    ex:hasDescription "Is not connected to the main thing at all." .
```

If I get a graph of that sort, what I mean is that everything here is connected, except `ex:thing-05` which has neither incoming nor outgoing connections.

What I'd like to do, is to get the subgraph that starts from `main-thing`, and includes everything that is connected (i.e. all `thing`s except `thing-05`).

I hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: every entity in an RDF graph is connected to at least something via an RDF triple, so I do not understand your use case. Any RDF node does not exists without occurring in a triple

Comment: regarding your question, where is the complexity of gathering any incoming and outgoing edges of a node? I mean, it's just getting all triples where the nodes does either occur in subject or object position, right?

Comment: you could use either API or SPARQL to get the direct neighbors of a given nodes I'd say

Comment: See my update for a clarification.

Comment: ok, thank's. So, the answer remains the same, either i) use SPARQL or ii) the API methods called recursively  - both work

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more "out-of-the-box"-y, than calling the API methods recursively (and avoiding infinite loops in circular connections). I'll have a look at how easily I can do it with SPARQL. Thanks for your comments!